# Silverlight AutoComplete Box Show SelectedItem Or Text

Tags: silverlight, autocompletebox

I'm using Silverlight's toolkit AutoCompleteBox control in a form where I want it to show the value bound to SelectedItem, or if it was null, then show the value bound to the Text property.

the problem is that when SelectedItem is null, it automatically clears the Text property, even when it was bound to a VM property that has a value.

here is some XAML:

```
<c:AutoCompleteBox
            MinimumPopulateDelay="500"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SuburbSearchResults}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSuburb}"
            Text="{Binding SuburbText, Mode=OneWay}"
            MinimumPrefixLength="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all using Binding on Text and SelectedItem properties together ? Maybe it's not a good idea.

Its right when you use binding on SelectedItem this manages Text properties value for you.

If you use a ViewModel, I suggest you to bind one property of AutocompleteBox and just use SuburbText prop. in VM. (or just bind SelectedItem and you may use ValueMemberPath with it)

**Edit 1:**

```
//Suppose myVM.SuburbText is a local variable in VM, this shows Text prp. binding
//But I prefer Object binding with ValueMemberPath,you may use one of them
//But not both together

public string TextWillBeBound
{
  get
  {
    if(SearchResults.SelectedItem!=null)
    {
      myVM.SuburbText=SearchResults.SelectedItem.TextProperty;
    }
  else if(myVM.SuburbText="")
 {
   myVM.SuburbText="Please write...";
 }
  return myVM.SuburbText;
}
set
 {
   if(SearchResults.SelectedItem==null)     
  { 
    myVm.SuburbText=value; 
    //with value you may create Suburb object ? and set as Selected. 
    //Depending  on what you aim. I suggest using SelectedItem & ValueMemberPath
  }
 }
}
```

//How did I used this control before

//You can also bind SelectedItem and use ValueMemberPath as shown below.

```
<sdk:AutoCompleteBox MinimumPopulateDelay="500" MinimumPrefixLength="3"
                     Populating="AutoCompleteBox_Populating"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SELECTEDITEM,Mode=TwoWay}"
                     ValueMemberPath="DESCRIPTION">
```

Comment: I'm using a VM and the need to have both properties is because the user should be able to enter a free text if he wants and the autocompletbox should display the SuburbText if SelectedSuburb == null.

Comment: I edited my post,TextWillBeBound will be in your VM's public property you may bind to Text property.You can also use TwoWay